# Finding a Basis of a Vector Space - Coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

I understand that first you have to prove that it's linearly independent, but wouldn't a coefficient of 0 always work?

Ex:

$a_1(u+v+w) + a_2(-2u+v-w) = 0$
For any vector, wouldn't $a_1 = a_2 = 0$ always hold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it holds and hence we call it the trivial solution.

What is of interest is to examine if there is any non-trivial solution. If there is only the trivial solution, it is linearly independent. Otherwise, it is linearly dependent.

Comment: How do I determine if there is a non-trivial solution?

Comment: By using the information that are given to you. In your example, if you already know that $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, then you might like to collect terms according to that and by linearly independent, we know the corresponding coefficient is equal to $0$ and carry on to solve for the unknown.